# Ways of selecting sets of consecutive numbers arranged in a circle

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Assume that you have 24 distinct numbers arranged in a circle. How many ways are there to choose two disjoint sets of adjacent numbers, one of size 2 and one of size 3? How would this change if the 24 numbers were instead arranged in 2 circles, each of size 12? What about in 8 circles of size 3?

Also, can anyone suggest a reference for dealing with problems of this kind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, we need to choose two "leading" elements $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{24}$ such that $b \not\in \{a,a+1\}$ and $a \not\in \{b,b+1,b+2\}$.  From this choice, we have the sets $\{a,a+1\}$ and $\{b,b+1,b+2\}$.  One such example is depicted below:

[image: Choosing $a=4$ and $b=17$]

In this case, there are no overlap, since $b \not\in \{a,a+1\}=\{4,5\}$ and $a \not\in \{b,b+1,b+2\}=\{17,18,19\}$.  If we had instead chosen $b \in \{2,3,4,5\}$, there would have been overlap.

Thus, the desired number is the number of pairs $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{24}$ that satisfy:

- $b \not\equiv a \pmod {24}$,
- $b \not\equiv a+1 \pmod {24}$,
- $a \not\equiv b \pmod {24}$ (although, this is the same as the first bulleted item),
- $a \not\equiv b+1 \pmod {24}$, and
- $a \not\equiv b+2 \pmod {24}$.

These congruences are equivalent to:

- $b \not\equiv a+1 \pmod {24}$,
- $b \not\equiv a \pmod {24}$,
- $b \not\equiv a-1 \pmod {24}$, and
- $b \not\equiv a-2 \pmod {24}$.

Thus, given any value of $a$, we can choose any $b \in \mathbb{Z}_{24} \setminus \{a+1,a,a-1,a-2\}$.

> Thus, there are $24$ choices for $a$ and, regardless of the choice of $a$, there are $20$ choices for $b$.  So $24 \times 20=480$ total ways to choose the two sets.

For the latter parts of the question, this same process can be applied, but some more bookkeeping is involved.  With two tables, there are four cases:

- $a$ and $b$ both are on Table 1,
- $a$ is on Table 1 and $b$ is on Table 2,
- $a$ is on Table 2 and $b$ is on Table 1,
- $a$ and $b$ both are on Table 2.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, how did you make the diagram with the seating arrangements?

Comment: Also, notice that in the case where there are two tables, using the method outlined above, we can see that if both a and b are on the same table there are 12 choices for a times (12-4=8) choices for b, times 2 tables = 192. If they are at different tables, we can select a and b from any of the 12 seats at their respective tables, giving 12*12*2=288 seating arrangements of this form. 192+288=480 which is the same number of seating arrangements as in the case of only one table. Is there a way to see that this will always be the case under some conditions?

Comment: I drew the figure using the [tikz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) LaTeX package (it takes a bit of getting used to).  Curious comment; I didn't think of that.  It's going to be the same since when you decide $a$, there will be $24-4$ ways of deciding $b$ (as in the first case).  This argument should work whenever all of the circle sizes are $4$ or more.

Comment: Oh yeah, right. That makes sense. Thanks! I'll look into getting tikz, too. That's nifty.